# How to join a table in mysql

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement is like :

```
select (*ALL columns of table1, [count of rows of TABLE2 where TABLE1.id  = Table2.id] 
from TABLE1, TABLE2 
where TABLE1.status = 'A'
```

Am now to SQL, please pardon if the question is too simple

Comment: (1) Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Those are two different products.  (2) Your question is vague and ambiguous.  Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, count(t2.id)
from table1 t1
left join TABLE2 t2 on t1.id  = t2.id
where t1.status = 'A'
group by t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id) AS Counter
FROM TABLE1 t1
WHERE t1.status = 'A';
```